# Passing parameters down in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using Post-Build actions plug-in in jenkins to call downstream jobs. Lets say I have job A, which calls job B, which in turn will call Job C. Some of the parameters passed to job A, will be required by job C. What is the cleanest way of passing the parameters from job A to job C. I know that I can pass it to job B, then pass those to job C. However I want every job to only have the parameters it needs, not parameters that will be needed by downstream jobs. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Trying to understand the actual problem. What is so bad about forwarding parameters through B to C? I could imagine that you don't want to change B's parameters everytime C's parameters change. If this is the case you could add a single parameter to B that will receive all C parameters serialized as JSON. Before calling C, deserialize JSON to the individual parameters (which can be a generic function) or just pass JSON along to C and let C deserialize it. This way B doesn't need to know about exact parameters of C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jenkins Parameterized Trigger plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger/)

And pass only those variables to next job which are required.
You can pass environment variable from a file as well as the variables present in current job.

Suppose you have X, Y, Z three variables in job A.
Then you can pass only Y, Z to job B and then only Z variable to job C, but that need to be configured in the respective jobs.